# A naval leader, without a boat

Tags: riddle

Please solve this riddle for me! I have been trying for an hour now and it's driving me crazy!

> A naval leader, but without a boat;
>   On water never was he meant to float,
>   Though unlike all the others of his ilk,
>   He took command upon a sea of milk.

**Who is he?**

Answer (score 6):

This seems more joke than riddle.
A  possible answer is

> Captain Crunch.

Answer (score 2):

My answer

> Cap 'n Crunch!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!

Comment: Ninja'ed you by 10 seconds. :)

Answer (score 0):

Oh my goodness I knew this when I was a kid!
the answer is:

> Captain crunch

Comment: How does this answer add to the answers already given? Please make sure to check existing answers before submitting one of your own, to avoid creating a duplicate.

Comment: Oh okay sorry Rubio. I didn't mean to steal the answer I just got excited when I saw a riddle that I knew when I was younger.